# Change the storage-directory of javamelody

Tags: java, monitoring, java-melody

I need to monitor java application and I am using javamelody.

But the problem is, I have to get the data that javamelody has so I can show it in another screen. I know that javamelody store its rdd files in temp/javamelody directory, now I need to change the storage-directory to another path so I can get the data from that path.

How can I set the storage-directory of javamelody?

Comment: `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/new/tmp yourjar` (on Linux) or setting `%TMP%` (on Windows) should do the trick.

Comment: the command can only be used for the project which has main class.
javamelody is a library and it doesn't have any main class. How can the command used for the library class which has no main class?

Comment: Hah, even better: http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide and scroll to `storage-directory`, this looks like what you want.

Comment: I have seen it but it doesn't provide any statement about how to do it

Comment: Right in the beginning of section 6, e.g. `-Djavamelody.storage-directory=/some/dir`.

Comment: Where should I type that command? I type it in javamelody temp directory and it gave me exception

Comment: This is not a command but a command option; you could set it anywhere where the startup options are set (e.g. startup script, tomcat properties file, etc). What kind of application do you have? Is it a servlet? What servlet container do you use in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh I think I've found the answer
I just have to set command line or xml file in my tomcat like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context docBase="pathto\appname.war" path="javamelody" reloadable="false" >
        <Parameter name='javamelody.storage-directory' value='pathname' override='false'/>
</Context>
```

Thank you for the help :D

Comment: In this case it is called "context parameter" (which is set in `context.xml` file), not the command-line option :) Glad you've managed, cheers ;)

Answer (score 2):

In web.xml, define filter `javamelody` with parameter `storage-directory` as below:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>javamelody</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>storage-directory</param-name>
        <param-value>/path/to/the/storage/directory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

I tested using JavaMelody version 1.60.0. For more information refer to [the JavaMelody user guide](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide).

Answer (score 1):

for **javamelody-spring-boot-starter**

```
 javamelody.init-parameters.storage-directory=/tmp/javamelody-${spring.application.name}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Spring Boot

```
public class JavaMelodyConfiguration implements ServletContextInitializer {

@Value(value="${javamelody.storage-directory}")
String jmStorageDir;

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
    servletContext.setInitParameter("javamelody.storage-directory", jmStorageDir);
}
```

then you can set the javamelody.storage-directory in application.properties

Comment: This is not the right way to integrate javamelody in Spring boot, neither to set javamelody parameters.
See https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter